# How to call update_password after request_reset in ng-token-auth and devise-token-auth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, authentication, devise

I am using rails api [devise-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and Angular Front with [ng-token-auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth). I am getting problems in the **Forgot Password?**.

***I want that after successful forgot password request, the user is allowed to login and redirected to my update_password path to change password.***

***The result is user gets login but the redirect url does not go to update_password path.***

My redirect url becomes from:  http://localhost:9000/#/auth/update_password to http://localhost:9000/?client_id=7gcm9TRnCY0BQh_q83ayPQ&config=default&expiry=&reset_password=true&token=e7Pf34gAC45GPemR6umXwQ&uid=email3%40email.com#/auth/update_password

please note that `#/auth/update_password` goes to end of link.

My **ng-route** is like below:

```
mainApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'views/pages/Home.html',
      controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    })
    .when('/auth/signup', {
      templateUrl: 'views/auth/signup.html',
      controller: 'authCtrl'
    })
    .when('/auth/signin', {
      templateUrl: 'views/auth/signin.html',
      controller: 'authCtrl'
    })
    .when('/auth/request_reset',{
      templateUrl: 'views/auth/requestResetPassword.html',
      controller: 'authCtrl'
    })
    .when('/auth/update_password',{
      templateUrl: 'view/auth/updatePassword.html',
      controller: 'authCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

My **ng-token-auth settings** are:

```
mainApp.constant('railsServer', 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1');
mainApp.constant('angServer', 'http://localhost:9000/#');

mainApp.config(function ($authProvider, angServer, railsServer) {
  $authProvider.configure({
    apiUrl: railsServer,
    storage: 'localStorage',
    confirmationSuccessUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/#/auth/update_password',
    passwordResetSuccessUrl: 'http://localhost:9000/#/auth/update_password'
  });
});
```

My **authCtrl** is:

```
var authApp = angular.module('authModule', []);

authApp.controller('authCtrl', ['$scope', '$auth', '$http', '$location', 'railsServer', '$log', function ($scope, $auth, $http, $location, railsServer, $log) {
  $scope.go = function (path) {
    $location.path(path);
  };

  var rails_server_path = railsServer;

  $scope.userSignUp = function (userSignUpForm) {
    $auth.submitRegistration(userSignUpForm)
      .then(function (resp) {
        $log.info("Welcome " + resp.data.data.email + " !");
      })
      .catch(function (resp) {
        $log.error(resp.data.errors.full_messages[0]);
      });
  };

  $scope.userSignIn = function (userSignInForm) {
    $auth.submitLogin(userSignInForm)
      .then(function (resp) {
        $log.info("Welcome " + resp.email + " !");
        $location.path('/#/')
      })
      .catch(function (resp) {
        $log.error(resp.errors[0]);
      });
  };

  $scope.userRequestReset = function(userRequestResetForm){
    $auth.requestPasswordReset(userRequestResetForm)
      .then(function(resp){
        $log.info(resp);
      })
      .catch(function(resp){
        $log.error(resp);
      });
  };

  $scope.userUpdatePassword = function(userUpdatePasswordForm){
    $auth.updatePassword(userUpdatePasswordForm)
      .then(function(resp){
        $log.info(resp);
      })
      .catch(function(resp){
        $log.error(resp.data.errors[0]);
      });
  };


}]);
```

My **devise-token-auth** setting are default settings.